# Сервис для работы с API (онлайн)

Tags: api

Здравствуйте. Я ищу сервис, с помощью которого можно было бы отправлять запросы по заданному адресу с заданными параметрами и получать ответ с этого адреса. Некий аналог расширения PostMan(для Google Chrome).

Сам я пользователь Firefox и подобного расширения я к сожалению не нашел. Я даже не нашел никакого подобного сервиса(онлайн), чтобы можно было выполнять действия указанные выше.

Нагуглить тоже ничего не удалось.

Может быть кто-нибудь из уважаемого сообщества HashCode мог бы подсказать подобный сервис? Потому что держать целый браузер ради одного лишь расширения как-то неудобно что ли. Почему то плохо себя чувствую из-за этого :)

Или может быть есть какие-нибудь специальные программы(Linux) для этого?

Comment: А может быть вам нужен просто [netcat](http://netcat.sourceforge.net/) или [curl](http://curl.haxx.se/)? Или вообще [wget](http://www.gnu.org/software/wget/).

Comment: @VladD, кстати да, можно и этим воспользоваться. Спасибо. Как-то совсем не подумал об этих инструментах. 

Но хотелось бы...красивостей что ли. Чтобы полученный JSON/XML(в моем случае JSON) как-то структурировался и подсвечивался. Что-то более человечное чем netcat. Хотя, опять же, большое спасибо за напоминание про netcat и curl. Если ничего не найдется то буду использовать netcat

Comment: Хм, ну можно скриптом открыть в редакторе, который понимает форматы. Хотя конечно неплохо бы из редактора потом запустить новый запрос.

Comment: О! А может быть вот это: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/live-http-headers/ ? Там и редактировать можно.

Comment: @VladD, пробовал. Это, к сожалению, совсем не то :(
Там даже нельзя указать адрес и POST параметры для запроса. Можно разве что захватить данные отправленные через Firefox, поменять параметры и отправить заново. Вообще много лишних действий нужно выполнить. Гораздо проще было бы использовать выше указанный curl или netcat.

Comment: Самый гибкий способ использовать сокет. Если отправка простая можно даже telnet. Всё зависит от задач и желаемого результата

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нашел дополнение под названием [Poster](http://screencloud.net/v/D2Op). Не совсем то, что я хотел бы(избалован я все таки Postman'ом) но уже ближе к истине :)

**ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ**

Нашел я таки то что хотел.
Итак. Главное окно выглядит [ТАК](http://screencloud.net/v/D2Op).

Ответ от сервера выглядит [очень-очень симпатично](http://screencloud.net/v/twIe).

Расширение называется [RESTClient](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/restclient/) и оно замечательное.

Всем большое спасибо :)

Answer (score 1):

[IFTTT](https://ifttt.com/wtf) ( if this then that ) ?